# Unit test ServiceStack services in ServiceStack 3.9.71

Tags: c#, unit-testing, servicestack, moq, xunit

I recently took a .Net project over which exposes DAOs from a Microsoft SQL Database via ServiceStack(3.9.71) REST API. Since I am gonna refactor some parts I want to unit test (at least) all servicestack services. For a better understanding I quickly draft how the implementation works.

Each Service contains a property of type `DBService` which encapsulates **all** database accesses of **all** services. Unfortunately this is a concrete class which makes it hard to mock. The `DI.Container` wrappes ServiceStack's `IOC`.

```
public class SomeService : Service
{
    public DBService { get { return DI.Container.Resolve<DBService>(); } } 

    public object Get(SomeDataClass class)
    {
       var response = DBService.SomeServiceGet();
       return response;
    }

    // other code omitted

}
```

The `DBService` looks like this (draft):

```
public class DBService 
{
     public IDbConnectionFactory DBFactory { get { return DI.Container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>(); } }
    public SomeServiceResponse SomeServiceGet()
    {
       //DB Access here...
       // ...
    }
    public SomeOtherServiceResponse SomeOtherServiceGet()
    {
       //...
    }

    // following about 30 other methods for all the services (POST,GET,PUT etc)
}
```

I read the detailed response to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998366/how-to-unit-test-servicestack) but I was not able to create and initialize a `BasicAppHost` in ServiceStack 3.9.71 since it immediately threw a `System.TypeLoadExceptionMethod 'get_VirtualPathProvider'`.

On the other hand I was thinking that I do not actually need a `BasicAppHost`. I just have to unit test the `DBService` and then the servicestack services with a somehow mocked `DBService`. The only problem I have is that `DBService` is not an interface and that I am actually not sure how to deal (mock) with the SQL database and the `IOC`.

**[UPDATE]**

Unfortunately I am still not able to test a service since I can not just `new` the service in my test. If I do so I get:

> System.TypeLoadExceptionCould not load type 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService' from assembly

Here is my test:

```
[Fact]
public void SomeDataTest()
{
   var serviceUnderTest = new SomeService();
   var response = serviceUnderTest.Get(new SomeDataClass());

   Assert.NotNull(response);
}
```

I guess the problem is that the services strongly uses alot of properties which are injected via the IOC. How can I mock that? Creating a `BasicAppHost` and retrieving the service from there also does not work which I already mentioned.

Comment: Once neither of the classes in question are sealed then you can create you own class that inherits them and overrides or new up the behavior desired for testing. It is hard to mock but not impossible.

Comment: so I actually don't have to care about the IOC injection of the `IDbConnectionFactory`? I am also wondering if it its a better approach so implement an interface for the `DBService` so I can easily mock it.

Comment: Yes abstracting the DbService would improve testability greatly and you should consider constructor injection as apposed to the Service Locator anti-pattern you are using

Comment: Show the unit test that is failing. along with any related classes as a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just testing your service class, then you can directly mock any dependencies:

```
[Fact]
public void SomeDataTest(
{
    var serviceUnderTest = new SomeService();

    var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();  // Rhino mocks fashion.
    serviceUnderTest.Logger = logger.Object;

    var response = serviceUnderTest.Get(new SomeDataClass());

   Assert.NotNull(response);
}
```

There's an page in their older docs [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HowTo-write-unit-integration-tests) about integration testing in case you want to test the `AppHost`

**Edit:** there's an example of mocking the service dependencies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9587745/2608).